# Is there a tool, program, extension to prevent and find code repetition in a project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, git, visual-studio-code

I've been looking for a VS Code / Git extension, add-on or anything that can help me *prevent* but to also identify code that is already repeated so I can abstract it away and reuse it.

You know, maybe even build a library for the darn app but I haven't found anything useful and fresh yet.

Comment: Repetition is not necessarily bad!

Comment: I understand there could be cases in which is OK to have code repetition or when you just can't get rid of it. But you're right I get your point and understand it's important to have a balance and not over do it.

Answer (score 1):

There is, but it is not free. WebStorm IDE or any there JetBrains IDE show code repetition and also give you a very good insight into your code. you can try it for free for 30 days and if you liked it then buy it.

[WebStorm - The smartest JavaScript IDE](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/)

Comment: Thanks! I like VS Code so this might not be the best option for me.

Answer (score 1):

Sonarlint is one of the best tool. It says code duplications and makes sure the code is good shape based on the best practices. You can also add that as a plugin in the VS Code.

Comment: This looks promising I will go ahead and try the extension and let you know!

Answer (score 1):

[SonarCube](https://www.sonarqube.org/) is the actual product you are looking for, it provide lot more than code duplication details.

Sonar Cube will do following things for you

1. Code Quality Check, it actually analyses your entire code and provides you information about Bugs and vulnerabilities
2. it also provides you code coverage on new-code which get pushed
3. it provides you information and graphs about code coverage, bugs etc.
4. it provides you information about code duplication

[image]

Comment: Thank you, tomorrow I will check at work if this tool is approved by InfoSec and will check if I would need to pay, I'll let you know what I find.

Comment: @TheDaniel this is well known tool and free version will be enough for starting.